# Should I denormalize a Cassandra table with 1B rows according to the queries being used?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I know that in a Cassandra table, inserts with the same **partition key** will overwrite the previous value. So, if we also insert 10 records with the same **primary key** it will do the same, meaning overwrite and store the 10th value only. Right?

So, I have the below table in my Cassandra database which has ~1 billion rows with ~4800 partition keys:

```
CREATE TABLE tb(
parkey varchar, //this is a UUID converted to String.
pk1 text,
pk2 float,
pk3 float,
pk4 float,
pk5 text,
pk6 text,
pk7 text,
PRIMARY KEY ((parkey),pk1, pk2, pk3, pk4, pk5, pk6, pk7));
```

This means I have ~1 billion primary keys!! I have such a big primary key because every record is unique only if it has all the values. However, I have a feeling this might not be the best table schema, as it also takes 5 minutes for spark to query all these data while it also hangs for another 10 minutes just before unpersisting a table from memory for which I do not know why!

Should I break down and denormalize the table somehow according to the queries being used? Will that improve the query times? **My thought is**, that even if I break down the table, I will still have ~1 billion primary keys for each denormalized table that will be created. Would that be efficient? Will it not take again 15 minutes to query the newly created tables?

**Edit 1**

I am always using 1 query that selects partition keys. Hence one table. Would this improve times?

```
CREATE TABLE tb(
parkey varchar, //this is a UUID converted to String.
pk1 varchar, //also a UUID but completely unique for every record
c1 text,
c2 float,
c3 float,
c4 float,
c5 text,
c6 text,
c7 text,
PRIMARY KEY ((parkey),pk1));
```

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. PS A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly" or "it is false that".

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! Just sometimes it is hard to focus on something (or know beforehand) when you do not know what the exact problem is! Thanks though! I will try and keep it in mind from now on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer is YES, you should denormalise the data and always start with the app queries. Those who come from a relational DB background tend to focus on how the data is stored (table schema) instead of listing all the app queries first.

By focusing on the app queries first THEN designing a table for each of the queries, the table is optimised for reads. If you try to adapt an app query to an existing table then the table will never be optimised and the queries will almost always be slow.

As a side note, the long answer is that 1B rows `!=` 1B partitions in the schema you posted. The table definition does not have a 1:1 mapping between rows and partitions. Each of the partitions in your table can have ONE OR MORE rows. Cheers!

Comment: Yes you are right, there is no 1:1 mapping! One partition has thousands of rows and it is true 1B rows != 1B partitions! However it is also true 1B rows = 1B primary keys! The point is that basically I have only ONE query. The user always selects a number of "parkey" fields and then the data are pulled! So, I think the obstacle here, and what causes spark to hang for 10mins after ML algorithm is completed according to SparkUI, is the big primary key! Could that be the case? I am thinking of implementing something like in Edit 1. Do you think it would change the behaviour?